# Powershell Active Directory Cmdlets: Quest or Microsoft

Tags: powershell

Is there any reason to choose Quest's Active Directory cmdlets over Microsoft's at this point?  I haven't come across anything that isn't doable with Microsoft's ActiveDirectory module yet, but I'm genuinely curious why Quest's are hanging around.  I realize they were quicker on the draw in bringing something bit more usable to the public, but that advantage has since passed.  Nonetheless, I still see innumerable references to the Quest cmdlets that make me thing I'm missing something.  Perhaps people just don't want to rewrite their already functioning scripts, which is also understandable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply; inertia.

Two things:

1. The effect that you're seeing.  People do a google search on how to do something, and the Quest cmdlets are used.  They download and work with them, not knowing there's an alternative.
2. Smaller install base of Windows 2008 R2 (a domain controller must be on R2 for AD Web Services to use the Microsoft cmdlets), so not everyone can use the Microsoft tools.

Comment: Actually, Windows Server 2008 R2 isn't even required.  You can run the Active Directory Management Gateway Service on any Windows 2003/2008 domain controller which gives you 99.99% of the functionality of Active Directory Web Services.  I don't have a Windows 2008 DC and I've been using this for a long time.  So apparently it's just inertia.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't even know that Microsoft had any AD cmdlets until this thread. Every time you search for "add user" scripts or whatever only the Quest stuff comes up as Shane has pointed out.

Thanks for bringing this to my attention and I guess it'll take a while for the MS stuff to climb the google search results. Until then, Powershell newbies like me will keep getting directed to Quest.

Answer (score 1):

We use the Quest AD cmdlets because we exclusively run 2003 servers and xp workstations still. Although, as you mentioned, you can run the gateway service on a 2003 domain controller, you still can only run the MS cmdlets from a NT 6.1 client (Win7/2008r2).

Comment: That's an important clarification.  Good catch!